# How to make right query builder with subqueries

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I have a table with payments and I need to get all table columns and four custom columns. My current working query:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('payments')
            ->select('DATE_FORMAT(payments.createdAt, \'%Y-%m\') as date_ym, payments')
            ->addSelect('(SELECT SUM(ps1.summ) FROM App\Entity\Payments ps1 WHERE ps1.isPayed = 1 AND ps1.type = 1 AND ps1.user = :user AND DATE_FORMAT(ps1.createdAt, \'%Y-%m\') = date_ym) as pay_in')
            ->addSelect('(SELECT COUNT(ps3.id) FROM App\Entity\Payments ps3 WHERE ps3.isPayed = 1 AND ps3.type = 1 AND ps3.user = :user AND DATE_FORMAT(ps3.createdAt, \'%Y-%m\') = date_ym) as pay_in_count')
            ->addSelect('(SELECT SUM(ps2.summ) FROM App\Entity\Payments ps2 WHERE ps2.isPayed = 1 AND ps2.type != 1 AND ps2.user = :user AND DATE_FORMAT(ps2.createdAt, \'%Y-%m\') = date_ym) as pay_out')
            ->addSelect('(SELECT COUNT(ps4.id) FROM App\Entity\Payments ps4 WHERE ps4.isPayed = 1 AND ps4.type != 1 AND ps4.user = :user AND DATE_FORMAT(ps4.createdAt, \'%Y-%m\') = date_ym) as pay_out_count')
            ->where('payments.user = :user')
            ->setParameter('user', $user)
            ->andWhere('payments.isPayed = 1')
            ->andWhere('payments.createdAt >= :days')
            ->setParameter('days', $days->format('Y-m-d'))
            ->orderBy('date_ym', 'DESC')
            ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

In controller I do:

```
$payments = $em->getRepository(Payments::class)->myFunc($user, 180);
$paymentsTable = [];
foreach ($payments as $payment) {
    $date = $payment['date_ym'];
    /** @var PaySchet $pay */
    $pay = $payment[0];
    $paymentsTable[$date]['pay_in'] = $payment['pay_in'];
    $paymentsTable[$date]['pay_in_count'] = $payment['pay_in_count'];
    $paymentsTable[$date]['pay_out'] = $payment['pay_out'];
    $paymentsTable[$date]['pay_out_count'] = $payment['pay_out_count'];
    $paymentsTable[$date]['data'][$pay->getType()][] = $pay;
}
```

I get the following result:

```
array:3 [▼
  "2020-03" => array:5 [▼
    "pay_in" => "15"
    "pay_in_count" => "1"
    "pay_out" => "230"
    "pay_out_count" => "1"
    "data" => array:1 [▼
      0 => App\Entity\Payments {#2288 ▶}
    ]
  ]
  "2020-01" => array:5 [▼
    "pay_in" => "2620"
    "pay_in_count" => "5"
    "pay_out" => "13732"
    "pay_out_count" => "3"
    "data" => array:3 [▼
      0 => App\Entity\Payments {#2267 ▶}
      1 => App\Entity\Payments {#2257 ▶}
      2 => App\Entity\Payments {#2251 ▶}
    ]
  ]
  "2019-12" => array:5 [▶]
]
```

It's correct output, but how can I improve my DQL query? I don't like how it looks like now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create multiple query builders and use them in the main one. Just beware that you must use unique entity aliases in all of them. You can use those aliases to reference entities from other query builders.

```php
/** @val $em EntityManager */

$query1 = $em->createQueryBuilder()->from(Payments::class, 'ps1')->select('')->getDql();
$query2 = $em->createQueryBuilder()->from(Payments::class, 'ps2')->select('')->getDql();
$query3 = $em->createQueryBuilder()->from(Payments::class, 'ps3')->select('')->getDql();
$query4 = $em->createQueryBuilder()->from(Payments::class, 'ps4')->select('')->getDql();

// All value binds need to be on the main query builder
$query = $qb->select('DATE_FORMAT(payments.createdAt, \'%Y-%m\') as date_ym, payments')
    ->addSelect($query1)
    ->addSelect($query2)
    ->addSelect($query3)
    ->addSelect($query4)
    ->from(Payments::class, 'payments')
    ->where('payments.user = :user')
    ->setParameter('user', $user)
    ->andWhere('payments.isPayed = 1')
    ->andWhere('payments.createdAt >= :days')
    ->setParameter('days', $days->format('Y-m-d'))
    ->orderBy('date_ym', 'DESC')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```